# jQuery: Ajax get request does not work with PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a simple script in order to pass a value in a PHP file.
This is the .js script:

```
$("#test").click(function () {
    var id = 34;
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("data sent");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Data sending failed");
        }
    });
});
```

And this is the code included in the PHP file:

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    echo $id;
}
```

The Ajax request works, but in the PHP file I receive an empty variable.

Comment: What element is `#test`? Is it an anchor, a button inside a form, a input of the type submit inside a form? ... If this is the case you might want to stop the default behavior of these controls before calling the ajax, otherwise your page will refresh. (`function(e) { e.preventDefault(); .... }`)

Comment: Post your HTML please.

Comment: the id test is a button...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `$_GET` global, if it's set there, you'll need to change `method: "POST"` to `type: "POST"`

Comment: Without changing method: "POST" to type: "POST" for me the code still worked. I got 34 in my ajax response.

Comment: From jquery docs: `method (default: 'GET')
Type: String
The HTTP method to use for the request (e.g. "POST", "GET", "PUT"). (version added: 1.9.0)`. If the OP has a version that's older, its not going to work.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info. :-)

Comment: As an alternative, there is also the shortcut [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)